# C++11 Variadic Template

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic

I got some example code to make a c++ variadic template from here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_template

My code is as follows.

```
#ifdef DEBUG
    #define logDebug(x, ...) streamPrintf( x, ##__VA_ARGS__ );
#else
    #define logDebug(x, ...)
#endif

void streamPrintf(const char *s);
template<typename T, typename... Args>
void streamPrintf(const char *s, T value, Args... args)
{
while (*s) {
    if (*s == '%') {
        if (*(s + 1) == '%') {
            ++s;
        }
        else {
            std::cout << value;
            streamPrintf(s + 1, args...); 
            return;
        }
    }
    std::cout << *s++;
}
throw std::logic_error("extra arguments provided to printf");
}

void streamPrintf(const char *s)
{
while (*s) {
    if (*s == '%') {
        if (*(s + 1) == '%') {
            ++s;
        }
        else {
            throw std::runtime_error("invalid format string: missing arguments");
        }
    }
    std::cout << *s++;
    }
}
```

But it prints only junk.  The main reason to use this is so I can print out std::string.  How can I print out the correct values?

I call the function like this:

```
logDebug("Event is, event=%", value);
```

Peter T found the problem via chat.  It does not print uint8_t correctly as it treats it like a ASCII.  It needs to be type cast to e.g. uint16_t.  When I have a solution, I will post it here.

Comment: Did you compile with all warnings and debug info (`gcc -std=c++11 -Wall -g`)? Did you use the debugger (`gdb`)?

Comment: Yes, I have all those flags.

Comment: Looks just [fine](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3cb5daa3767e0984) to me.

Comment: Did you use the `gdb` debugger to run your program step by step?

Comment: @Loopunroller, try passing a value into the function.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch No I have not done that.

Comment: @user1876942 What do you mean? I am passing values into the function (template), two `std::string`s and an integer. Edit:Alright, i see your edit.

Comment: @Loopunroller - I edited my question, see my example

Comment: @user1876942 You do realize that this `streamPrintf`-template doesn't consider format specifiers? All it takes is the percentage sign `'%'`, anything after that is just printed out.

Comment: @Loopunroller - Yes, I tried that but still problems, then I just tried anything.  I will edit my question.

Comment: @user1876942 What **are** the problems? When i compile your code like this it works *just* like I expected. Do you use VC++?

Comment: Nope, even VC++ is [doing the job](http://rextester.com/XVVHX51461). I really can't reproduce your problems, could you provide us with a complete test program?

Comment: @Loopunroller  it compiles OK but does not print the values, I see blank or a square box.

Comment: @Loopunroller  OK, it works for you, I will need to investigate why not for me.  I did exactly what you did.

Comment: is this correct?  #define logDebug(x, ...) streamPrintf( x, ##__VA_ARGS__ );

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62518/discussion-between-loopunroller-and-user1876942).

Comment: "But it prints only junk." What does that mean? Just post complete program and the output you get.

Answer (score 1):

A good example for using variadic templates with printf can be found here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn439779.aspx

```
void print() {
    cout << endl;
}

template <typename T> void print(const T& t) {
    cout << t << endl;
}

template <typename First, typename... Rest> void print(const First& first, const Rest&... rest) {
    cout << first << ", ";
    print(rest...); // recursive call using pack expansion syntax
}

int main()
{
    print(); // calls first overload, outputting only a newline
    print(1); // calls second overload

    // these call the third overload, the variadic template, 
    // which uses recursion as needed.
    print(10, 20);
    print(100, 200, 300);
    print("first", 2, "third", 3.14159);
}
```

Comment: Answers that only have a link aren't very good; the links rot. Try to at least sum up the article.